# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix on library

Tags: android, xml

I am using three libraries in my project:

```
a. ViewPager
b. SherlockActionBar
c. PagerSlidingTabStrip
```

In my layout xml, I am getting the following `error parsing XML` in here:

```
<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/strips"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:indicatorColor="#FF9326"
    app:textAllCaps="false" />
```

I implemented the library same as the two other libraries used in the project. The other two libraries are running smoothly. Error only exists within this. Please help.

Full layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainSlider" >

    <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/strips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        app:indicatorColor="#FF9326"
        app:textAllCaps="false" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have already tried cleaning the project, re-adding library to the workspace, etc.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Try to add custom properties reference using `res-auto` xmlns schemas**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainSlider" >

    <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/strips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        app:indicatorColor="#FF9326"
        app:textAllCaps="false" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: goddamn ... that worked ... I just deleted the project and am now restarting it, feel stupid now. `xmlns:app` was that all it needed ?? Thank you very very much :)

Comment: Yes becz we try to use custom view properties tht y.

Comment: nice and Simple !!

Answer (score 19):

Add

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to the root layout of the xml.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a `LinearLayout` as my root XML element.
I had an `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` instead because I was using the **AppCompat Library**.

**So, this was what I did:**
** I included the `tools:context=".classname"` line and that's where the `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix` comes from (in part). It's brought about when you referrence a *path* that Eclipse/Studio can't *see* when it's building your ***xml layout***.

**Solution:**
I added the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to point ADT to my `tools` location, and we were good to go!

**FINAL CODE:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".home"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Root element of every xml** have to contain:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

And you can use `android` attributes after.

Answer (score 0):

there is already a root element

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.arifa.model.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove and add this again:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Then clean and build the project.